# Javascript: sepia or duotone image effects?

Tags: javascript, image, visual-effects

Are there any reasonably easy to use JS frameworks/libraries for image effects, that would allow me to like converting an image (or part of an image) to b/w, sepia or duotone?

Or, for example, that would allow me to overlap images and use blending modes like Screen, Multiple, etc?

I tend to use jQuery, so a jQuery plugin would be ideal.

Comment: just a quick comment to add that filter: sepia(100%); it works in all modern browsers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this jQuery [plugin](http://dfsq.info/site/read/jquery-image-halftone) could be useful for you. It can convert an image to b/w or halftone.

Answer (score 0):

For JS only this is hard to do, and I personally am not aware of any way to do this at present. There are web services out there that will do that. One such is http://developers.aviary.com/.

Comment: The link you provided is an SDK and not an API.

Comment: Haha When I posted the link in 2011, it was an API.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to (sepia) tone an image that has been drawn to a `<canvas>`, if you OK with using those:

[How can I use a gradient map to tone a HTML5 canvas with an image in the canvas.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862875/how-can-i-use-a-gradient-map-to-tone-a-html5-canvas-with-an-image-in-the-canvas/6864272#6864272)