# JavaScript - Change BitDepth of a Image

Tags: javascript, image, client-side, bit-depth

I have an MVC application where I need to shrink the size of a Image. To do that I also reduce the bit depth to max. 8 bits. I've got all the code in a Controller but now I want to get it from the server to the client.
How can I reduce the bit depth of an image in JavaScript or some other client side solution ?

Some pseudo code:

```
function ScaleImage(image) {
    var ration = GetSize(image);

    if (image.bitdepth > 8) {
        ReduceBitDepth(image)
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Use [PHP Image magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [convert -depth](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

Comment: @skobaljic - php is server side

Comment: `client side solution` - not going to happen

Comment: Maybe using [canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895568/change-color-depth-of-html5-canvas-element).

Comment: @skobaljic - I think you can safely remove the "maybe". It is either canvas or file api to decompose calculate and compose again the image, which seems a lot more work.